# android 9 sdk compatibility with jdk 8

Tags: android-sdk

Is android 9 sdk installation not compatibile with jdk 8 for running avd ?
I tried running but got error of;

```
"emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is compatible with `jdk 8` (which is what I have in my setup). Perhaps you need to setup its `path` correctly in System Variables.

Not sure what the result of this was, but I have encountered the same error when I first ran android 9 on standalone sdk manager. What I did in my case was to **[upgrade the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)**, which altogether solved the issue, perhaps is the same scenario, firstly try upgrading the emulator and see if it solves the issue.

You can also try editing `image.sysdir.1` value to a full AVD path e.g `image.sysdir.1=C:\androidsdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\`  as suggested by [Akintunde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51796985/7551330)

(I see some suggestions that you should rename `kernel-ranchu` to `kernel-qemu` in the system image folder but this didn't work as I hoped, the AVD screen just went black.)